# Remote Desktop Services login history for specific user

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I found a script here: https://serverfault.com/questions/479048/remote-desktop-services-login-history

Here is the script:

```
Get-Eventlog -LogName Security | where {$_.EventId -eq "4624"} | select-object @{Name="User"
;Expression={$_.ReplacementStrings[5]}}  | sort-object User -unique |ogv
```

The goal is to search for a specific user and see when was the last time that he have login to the terminal server, and with that script, i'am unable to make it to show the date too, only the user name, I've tried to add some property after running get-member, but didn't got any success

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet for this like below:

```
$user = 'The SamAccountName of the user you want to track'

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=4624} -MaxEvents 100 | 
    Where-Object {$_.Properties[5].Value -eq $user } |
    Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'UserName'; Expression = { $_.Properties[5].Value }}, 
                            @{Name = 'LogonTime'; Expression = { $_.TimeCreated }},
                            MachineName | 
    Out-GridView

# $_.Properties[5].Value --> TargetUserName
```

<sup>The `-MaxEvents 100` is just an example. Change that value or remove the parameter alltogether if you need to</sup>

---

To retrieve only 3events, use the `-MaxEvents` parameter with value 3.
You can also select the (last) 3 events afterwards if that is what you want by appending `-Last 3` to the `Select-Object` command.

To see what the Properties array contains for this event ID, you can do

```
$props = (Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=4624}).Properties
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $props.Count; $i++) {
    "Properties[$i].Value --> {0}" -f $props[$i].Value
}
```

Comparing this to what you can read in the XML-view of eventvwr.exe:

```
SubjectUserSid            = 0
SubjectUserName           = 1
SubjectDomainName         = 2
SubjectLogonId            = 3
TargetUserSid             = 4
TargetUserName            = 5
TargetDomainName          = 6
TargetLogonId             = 7
LogonType                 = 8
LogonProcessName          = 9
AuthenticationPackageName = 10
WorkstationName           = 11
LogonGuid                 = 12
TransmittedServices       = 13
LmPackageName             = 14
KeyLength                 = 15
ProcessId                 = 16
ProcessName               = 17
IpAddress                 = 18
IpPort                    = 19
```

These values differ when asking for other events and are only valid for `LogName='Security';ID=4624`

Comment: Thank you,
I've tried that, it's now showing any thing, the grid view is not pops up

Comment: Sorry @theo we both were writing answers at the same time and fall on a embrassing situation now what to do about my answer? :(

Comment: @WebsGhost Try without the `Out-GridView` and see what you get in the console. You did set the `$user` to the accountname of the user you want to track? Did you try without `-MaxEvents 100`?

Comment: @Theo i'm i'm trying to make it to show me only 3 event's but it's not working if i'am adding the `-last` parameter. and one more question how did you know to use [5] in this part `{$_.Properties[5].Value -eq $user }` of the script? i've used gm but i didn't got it, thank you for your help

Comment: @WebsGhost I have added some explanation to the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it is, thank you very much :)
there is only one more thing that is happening, is that in the end of the script, the windows of powershell closes it self, i tried to add "pause", or any other "read-host", "write-host" commands to make it stop in the end, and actually, powershell would not show any output when i use it (in the console), would you assist with that please?

Comment: @WebsGhost Why not simply use the Powershell ISE editor to load, edit and run code? You can also run the script with the NoExit switch: `PowerShell -NoExit "C:\SomeFolder\SomeScript.ps1"`

Comment: I've running it exactly that way, but it's comfortable to run from the console, i didn't try the code yet, but i will update when i'll do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with help from https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2067489-powershell-script-to-get-rdp-session-history

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='Security';ID=4624} | Where-Object {$_.Properties[5].Value -eq 'UserName'} | Select-Object @{n='User';e={$_.Properties[5].Value}},@{n='Logon time';e={$_.Timecreated}}
```

Replace 'UserName' with your desired user.

Comment: Hello,
Thank your for your help, this showing only the name of the user, i need the name of the user and the date when he logged in to the terminal last time